# Query works locally not online

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this simple query that works when I try it locally but not online, probably some version difference?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'blah blah' WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

This query is working locally but online I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'blah blah' at line 1

Server info phpmyadmin, php version seems to be 5.5 it refers to this manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html

Comment: Your query might contain invisible hard spaces, or other tricky characters. Is the WordPress table prefix (`wp_`) the same on the live and the dev site?

Comment: errors related to something working on one server and not other are usually because of different mysql version. First of all make sure that you are using the exact same code on both the servers and then check for mysql version.

Comment: This smells like an errant call to `addslashes()` or similar...

Comment: Yep the sql version is probly different but how should it be changed then? Sql on server is 5.5, I'm calling this by going to the database then in the sql tab i enter the code and press go, basicly same as offline.

Comment: Probably phpMyAdmin adding its own string escaping after [PHP magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) already did it once.

Comment: So what would I have to change then eggyal?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE `databaseName`.`wp_posts` SET `post_content` = 'blah blah' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'product';
```

Comment: I tried this, I think using ` instead of ' made a difference now it says
#1054 - Unknown column 'product' in 'where clause'

Comment: it would be great if you copy-paste and run the above query 'as it is' and then narrow down if it works and post your feedback over here

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 55
STR: '
SQL: UPDATE `admin_wijnen`.`wp_posts` SET `post_content` = \'blah blah\' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = \'product\';

SQL query:

UPDATE `admin_wijnen`.`wp_posts` SET `post_content` = \'blah blah\' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = \'product\';

MySQL said:

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'blah blah\' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = \'product\'' at line 1

Comment: Copy pasted changed databasename and ran it

Comment: what it says if instead of 'blah blah' you just write 'blah' in the above query

Comment: SQL query:

UPDATE `admin_wijnen`.`wp_posts` SET `post_content` = \'blah\' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = \'product\';

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'blah\' WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = \'product\'' at line 1

Comment: good..as you have got phpmyadmin so just show try an update from there and let us know the query that it runs..

Comment: dont understand what you mean? I found the details of myphp. I dont know how or If i can update database I run it from a VPS

phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3

MySQL client version: 5.1.63
Used PHP extensions: mysql

Comment: update the record through phpmyadmin GUI and not by running the query..if you can't update then do an insert but not by typing query..let phpmyadmin do it for you..

Comment: No clue how to do it like that :(